# MySQL 8.0.26 doesn't start after saving my.ini

Tags: mysql

This is a fresh install of the latest version of MySQL at the time of writing (8.0.26) on a fresh install of a Windows 2019 Server Std, on a new HP ProLiant DL360 G10.

After installation and some configuration, I found that the MySQL80 service would not start back up if I stopped it. After a lot of reinstallations, I found that just saving the my.ini file was causing that. And by saving, I don't mean modifying anything -- just the act of opening it in Notepad and hitting save causes this issue.

I have not found a way to revert to a state where it starts again without reinstalling the service so the original file is recreated.

Is this a problem with this particular version? Could this be an issue with the file encoding or something? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: Just wanted to add that the log files don't get updated by the attempt at starting the service. The last entries are always about the last shutdown I did.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Notepad++ and opened both the modified file and the original, and they indeed have different encodings. The original was UTF-8, and the modified file is UTF-8-BOM.

I changed the encoding back to UTF-8 on the modified file, and it solved the issue.

So, apparently, the problem is that MS Notepad changes the encoding to UTF-8-BOM, and that causes MySQL to fail to start.

Comment: Suggest you file a bug report ( bugs.mysql.com ) suggesting that they accept the file even if it starts with BOM.